# OpenLayers 3, Why the WMS layer does not appear?

Tags: openlayers-3, wms

I would like for a "Vumop" layer to appear in
http://www.4dprostor.cz/nesvacily-vumop.html

I tried with the following code (OL9 v3.9.0):

```
var Vumop = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
url: 'http://geoportal.vumop.cz/wms_vumop/zchbpej.asp',
params: {'LAYERS': 'tro',
'TILED': true}
})
});
```

The URL is correct, the name of the layer is correct, the CRS is correct. Everything works correctly in QGIS.
Anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The response given when OpenLayers tries to load the tiles is a WMS error, containing:

> msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Invalid CRS given : CRS must be valid for all requested layers. msProcessProjection(): Projection library error. no options found in 'init' file

Changing the CRS from `EPSG:3857` to `EPSG:4326` returns a tile. Does the WMS server not support `EPSG:3857`?